# How to embed a google map of an address into a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-maps

I have a google sheet and I have cell `B1` called `Address` which contains:

> 405 E 42nd St, New York, NY 10017

I would like to embed a google map into my google sheet in cell `D5` that looks like this:

[image]

Note: I don't need other landmarks, but if they are there it won't bother me.

Research:

I googled it, and came up with zilch. I found code on how to import an image, but that's not the hard part. The hard part is getting the image of the map, or better yet, embedding a live dynamic map that changes when the address on the sheet changes (preferable).

I can use this api to get a static image:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=405%20E%2042nd%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010017&size=600x300&key={myApiKey}

[image: static map]

but I don't know how to get it into the sheet.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén ok I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;Dr
Try `=IMAGE(url)` and if that doesn't work as you need it use Google Apps Script and the [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) to insert the map as an [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) object.

---

Few weeks ago Google announced that now is possible to insert an image into a cell. Below is the insert image into a cell dialog:

[image: Google Sheets Insert Image dialog]

I don't think that it could be used to automatically update an image when a cell value changes. That could be done by using `IMAGE` built-in function if the image is public. As the Google MAP Static require an **API key** and because it response could exceed the time execution limit of `IMAGE`, it could me more reliable to use Google Apps Script but it's known that on edit triggers works on a "best effort" basis (meaning that now always are triggered like when a several cells are updated in short time)

---

To use Google Apps Script

1. Spreadsheet Service to have read/write access to the spreadsheet and have access to Class Sheet and [Class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image)
2. [Url Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) to get the image from [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)
3. On edit trigger to make the spreadsheet be updated when `B1` (or any other cell that you want to use as trigger) is edited by a user by using the Google Sheets UI.